# How to make a clearinterval/stop in discord.js?

Tags: discord, discord.js

I cant get it so if I do !stop it stops the interval and it just really annoys me.

```
client.on('message', msg => {
  if (msg.guild && msg.content.startsWith('!messageall')) {
    let text = msg.content.slice('!messageall'.length); // cuts off the /private part
     setInterval(function(){ 
    msg.guild.members.forEach(member => {
      if (member.id != client.user.id && !member.user.bot) member.send("Message Here");
      msg.channel.send(`Sent a message to <@${member.id}> `)
    });
       console.log("Started.")
       }, 60000);
  }
      if (msg.guild && msg.content.startsWith('!stopall')) {
      clearInterval()
    }
});
```

I dont know how it will work

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a reference to `setInterval()`, I also suggest you use [`client.setInterval()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=setInterval) instead, so what you should do is:

```js
const timer = client.setInterval(function(), 60000);
if (msg.guild && msg.content.startsWith('!stopall')) clearInterval(timer)
```